# Proof - for all integers $y$, there is integer $x$ so that $x^3 + x = y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

For all integers $y$, there is an integer $x$ so that $$x^3 + x = y.$$

This is what I have done so far:

Proof: Suppose $y$ is some integer. We want to prove that $$x^3 + x = y$$ for some integer $x$.

I am thinking this is false. For example, if $y = 1$, there is no integer $x$ so that $x^3 + x = 1$. But I am not sure how to start about expressing this as a formal proof. Any help please?

Comment: $y = 1$ is indeed a counterexample. Think about the fact that $x^3 > 0$ iff $x > 0$ and find an easy contradiction.

Comment: What do you think about $y=3$ ?

Answer (score 15):

Observe that $x^3+x=x(x^2+1)$ is a composite number if $x>1$, so can never represent a prime.

Comment: I don't care if it is prime or not, as long as it is integer.

Comment: So in particular no prime number >2 can be represented as $x^3+x$

Comment: We are not talking about prime numbers, @Sameer Kulkarni

Comment: You can aso combine the two observations, you will have $1=x(x^2+1)$ hence $x\neq 0$ hence $1$ has a divisor $x^2+1$ bigger than $1$ which is a contradiction

Comment: @Samim Every prime number is a integer. There exists a prime number that cannot be expressed using $x^3+x$. Therefore there exists an integer number that cannot be expressed using $x^3+x$

Comment: @Samim Pick any prime for $y$, say $y=3$. The point is then that there is no integer value of $x$ that will satisfy $x^3 + x = 3$. Your claim is that for any value of $y$ there is some integer value of $x$ that will satisfy $x^3 + x = y$, but a counterexample has just been provided...

Comment: how about this: Negation: There exists an integer y, such that for all integers x, x^3 + x ≠ y.
Proof: Let y be a prime number 1. Suppose x^3 + x = y, we will prove by contradiction. Then 

y = x^3 + x
1 = x^3 + x
1 = x(x^2 + 1), hence x ≠ 0

however, x^2 + 1 > 1, which contradicts with 1 = x(x^2 + 1). Therefore, x ≠ y.

Comment: @Samim But you ARE talking about prime numbers. Prime numbers are integers, so once you declared you're taking about integers, you ARE talking about primes among them. If your clam has to hold for all integers, it certainly must in particular hold for primes.

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed not true. Two proofs:

---

**Using basic calculus:**

Note that $x^3+x$ is strictly increasing. (Its derivative is $3x^2+1$ and squares are positive)

Now note that $1^3+1=2$ and $0^3+0=0$. Therefore the $x$ such that $x^3+x=1$ must statistify $0<x<1$, so its not an integer.

---

**Using number theory only:**

Note that $x \mid x^3+x$, so $x^3+x=0$ or $|x^3+x|\geq |x|$. Thus it can only be 1, 0 or -1 if it is equal to one. But $x=-1$ gives $x^3+x=-2$, $x=0$ gives $x^3+x=0$ and $x=1$ gives $x^3+x=2$. So it is not possible for an integer.

Comment: This proof makes sense to me, but how do I express it as formal proof. Don't I have to show how a general solution?

Comment: Yes you would need to do so if it was actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to use. My first thought:

use the intermediate value theorem to show that $$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R,x\mapsto x^3+x-1$$ has a root between $0$ and $1$. Then show that $f$ is strictly increasing. So in this proof I use mainly some basic calculus.

On second thought, one could use, that for a polynominal $f(x)=x^n+\dots a_1x+a_0$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ the following holds:
$$f(x_0)=0 \iff x_0\mid a_0.$$

Here we have $f(x)=x^3+x-1$, so $f(x_0)=0 \iff x_0=\pm 1$ and we can just pluck these two values in to see that $f$ doesn't have any (integer) roots.

Edit: of course there are other methods to proof this (see other answers), I mainly wanted to point out, that you don't have "the one proof" but depending on the context in which the problem arises, one usually has different approchaches (for a calculus class the first proof would be perfectly fine, for an algebra class not so).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
This is false.
Negation: There exists an integer $y$, such that for all integers $x$, $$x^3 + x \neq y.$$
Proof: Let $y$ = 1. Suppose $x^3 + x = y$, we will prove by contradiction. Then

$$y = x^3 + x$$
$$1 = x^3 + x$$
$$1 = x(x^2 + 1),~\text{hence}~ x \neq 0$$

however, $x^2 + 1 > 1$ where $x \neq 0$, which contradicts with $1 = x(x^2 + 1)$. Therefore, $x \neq y$.

Comment: 1 isn't a prime.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks - but 1 is a counter example. How is this proof? Is it correct?

Comment: Samim: If in your statement every *positive integer* $y$ can be written as $x^3+x$ for a positive integer $x$ then indeed $y=1$ is a counterexample. But somehow one of the proof ideas is to factor $x^3+x=x(x^2+1)$ which is not a prime unless $x=1$ (then it is $2$ which is the smallest prime). What this shows is that one can choose any odd prime $y$ and it will be a counterexample. That is, the only way the factorization shows $y$ can't be represented (without further work) is for $y$ to be an odd prime, or for $y=1$.solution $x$... Hmm, for which $y$ does it have a solution?